# Requires a check box array using Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I need an array of check-box that should look like as following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myname[]" >
```

Currently I am using

```
new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('myname[]');
```

but it doesn't show the array in html control. It draw this as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myname">
```

AnySolution?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$myname = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('myname');
$myname->setLabel('This is my label')
       ->setRequired(true)
       ->addMultiOptions(array('myname' => true));
```

Comment: Message: Method addMultiOptions does not exist

Comment: @clime http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiCheckbox

Comment: So i guess you wanted to use MultiCheckbox instead of normal Checkbox? But then you dont need to ->addMultiOptions. I have tried your example and it does print an error.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work anymore due version change. It did work before.

Comment: method name is `setMultiOptions `