# Using array notations for form elements names in Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

In a form I'm building using Zend_Form on Zend Framework project, I need to have a variable number of textareas. I need them to be posted with the array notation so I can use them.

Without Zend_Form, this is easily done adding square brackets to the name of the textareas:

```
<textarea name="mytext[]">one</textarea>
<textarea name="mytext[]">two</textarea>
```

I can't accomplish this using Zend_Form:

```
$t = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea("mytext[]");
$t->setValue("one");
$myForm->addElement($t);
$t = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea("mytext[]");
$t->setValue("two");
$myForm->addElement($t);
```

The two textareas are rendered in the view with the name attrib set to "mytext".

How can I use the array notations in this situation?

Comment: Same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145198/requires-a-check-box-array-using-zend-form-element-checkbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Zend Form to use Array Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928551/how-do-configure-zend-form-to-use-array-notation)

Comment: @Enrico: textarea objects do not inherit from Zend_Form_Element_Multi, so they do not have the addMultiOptions() method mentioned in the answer to the question you linked.

Comment: Gordon: thanks, the question you linked pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the form unpredictable number of textarea, I think you should use **sub_forms**.

```
$subForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$subForm->addElement(....);

$form->addSubForm($subForm, 'subform');
```

[Zend_Form (Sub Form)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html)

Regards.